# How to override jhipster command to launch generator?

Tags: node.js, generator, jhipster

Suppose I would like to change the jhipster command to another name in order to launch the application generator, which source file(s) do I need to modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check where your npm global binaries (like `jhipster` command) are installed:

`npm bin -g`

In this folder, you'll find 2 files `jhipster` and `jhipster.cmd`, create a link to them with desired name or rename them and you're done.

Now, assuming you want to create your own distribution of jhipster while 
 respecting the terms of its Apache 2.0 licence, you should edit the `package.json` of generator-jhipster and change the `bin` section.

```
"bin": {
    "jhipster": "./cli/jhipster.js",
    "my_jhipster_copy": "./cli/jhipster.js"
},
```

`npm install` will create your `my_jhipster_copy` command

Comment: does changing bin section in package.json do anything besides respecting its license?

Comment: What do you mean? JHipster is licensed under Apache 2.0, if you modify it and distribute it you must make sure you respect the terms of the license. I don't see how package.json is related to this.

Comment: Accepted, thanks. Would you mind answering this question as well please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960459/how-to-generate-jhipster-application-into-a-different-directory